# Can these sigils Ned saw at the tourney be identified?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, object-identification

In the first book *A Game of Thrones*, during the tourney being held in honor of the new Hand of the King, Ned is walking through the ground and notices the following sigils:

> The shields displayed out each tent heralded its occupant: the silver eagle of Seagard, Bryce Caron's field of nightingales, a cluster of grapes for the Redwynes, **brindled boar, red ox, burning tree, white ram, triple spiral, purple unicorn, dancing maiden, blackadder, twin towers, horned owl**, and last the pure white blazons of the Kingsguard, shining like the dawn. - *A Game of Thrones, Chapter 30*

So the first few are identified, but what about the others? **Do we know the names of the house they belong to?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Brindled Boar:

This is sigil of House [Crakehall](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Crakehall). They are a vassal of House Lannister and their current lord is Roland Crakehall. Their seat is Crakehall and their words are *None So Fierce*.

[image]

#### Red Ox:

This is sigil of House [Prester](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Prester). They are vassals to House Lannister and their current lord is Garrison Prester. Their seat is Feastfires and their words are *Tireless*.

[image]

#### Burning Tree:

This is sigil of House [Marbrand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Marbrand). They are a vassal of House Lannister and their current lord is Damon Marbrand. Their seat is Ashemark and their words are *Burning Bright*.

[image]

#### White Ram:

This is sigil of knightly House [Rambton](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Rambton). They are a vassal of House Sunglass (Who are vassals of House Baratheon of Dragonstone, previously House Targaryen) and their last known lord was Ser Hubart Rambton. Their words and seat are unknown.

[image]

#### Triple Spiral:

This is sigil of House [Massey](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Massey). They are direct vassals of the Royal dynasty and their current lord is unknown. Their seat is Stonedance however their words are also unknown.

[image]

#### Purple Unicorn:

This is sigil of House [Brax](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Brax). They are bannermen to Lord of Casterly Rock and their current lord is Tytos Brax. Their seat is Hornvale and their words are unknown.

[image]

#### Dancing Maiden:

This is sigil of House [Piper](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Piper). They are bannermen to House Baelish (Previously House Tully) and their current lord is Clement Piper. Their seat is Pinkmaiden but their words are unknown as per canon sources. Semi Canon sources put it as *Bright and Beautiful*.

[image]

#### Black Adder:

This is sigil of House [Wyl](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Wyl). They are bannermen to House Martell and their current lord is unknown. Their seat is Wyl and their words are unknown.

[image]

#### Twin Towers:

This is sigil of House [Frey](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Frey). They are bannermen to House Baelish (Previously House Tully) and their current lord is Walder Frey. Their seat is the Crossing/Twin towers of Frey and their words are unknown.

[image]

#### Horned Owl:

This is sigil of House [Mertyns](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Mertyns). They are bannermen to House Baratheon of Storm's End (Not House Baratheon of King's Landing) and their current lady is Mary Mertyns. Their seat is Mistwood and their words are unknown.

[image]

Comment: We can only hope that House Wyl’s words are “As cunning as a fox who's just been appointed Professor of Cunning at Oxford University”.